# how to align two input field and div inline

Tags: javascript, css, django, html

html:

```
<tr>
   <td><input style="margin: 2px;" type="button" name="delete"  class="delete_types" id="delete_name"/>
<a href="{% url setting.views.type_list type.id %}" style="color:black"><div class="rounded_list">{{type.title}} <span style="float:right;" > {{ type.is_active|yesno:"On,Off" }} ></span></div></a>
<input style="margin: 2px;" type="button" name="delete"  value="Delete" id="{{ type.id }}" class="type_delete"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to keep the two input button and middle div into same line.Now it looks in below screen shot.I am working in django framework.I tried with `display:inline` and `display:block` not making any sense.Please help

[image: Please see this]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `float:left;` to show them inline.

**For Instance,**

```
<input type="button" id="delete_name" class="delete_types" name="delete" style="margin: 2px; float: left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

```
        <tr>
            <td><div style="width=20%;float:left"><input style="margin: 2px;" type="button" name="delete"  class="delete_types" id="delete_name"/></div>
            <a href="{% url setting.views.type_list type.id %}" style="color:black"><div style="width=20%;float:left" class="rounded_list">{{type.title}} <span style="float:right;" > {{ type.is_active|yesno:"On,Off" }} ></span></div></a>
            <div style="width=20%;float:right"><input style="margin: 2px;" type="button" name="delete"  value="Delete" id="{{ type.id }}" class="type_delete"/></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```